# How to create a user with password for Azure SQL Edge using SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am running the [Azure SQL Edge Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-sql-edge) and connect to it via SQL Server Management Studio.

Security - Users - New User only gives me these options:

[image]

I am new to SQL Server, but I would have expected an option to create a user with a password for my application? (don't want to use the administrator account for it of course)

Comment: From SSMS Object Explorer, right-click on the instance Security node (not database) and select new login. Specify SQL authentication along the password and map the user to your database on the User Mapping page. Can also be done using T-SQL `CREATE LOGIN YourUser WITH PASSWORD='Y0urUserP@ssword';USE YourDatabase;CREATE USER YourUser;`

Comment: `USER`s *can* have passwords if the database is a contained database, but I suspect that is not what you want here.

Comment: So to the Security node for the server instance, not the database; there you'll right-click Logins (not Users). Or just learn the commands like Dan described.